# Can't configure vlan on device

Tags: networking, linux-networking, vlan

I'm new at vlan implementation.

I'm trying to manually configure a vlan on my target device. I use these 2 vlan config commands, then I ping an IP address and sniff the packets to look for the vlan tag in the messages.

```
vconfig add esw0
ifconfig esw0.10 10.93.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Despite my attempts tagging does **not** occur in any outgoing packets.

However when I tried the exact same method and commands on my Ubuntu workstation vlan tagging did work without problems.

```
Target: mips32, Linux 2.6.39, 802.1Q driver version 1.8
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Here is a log of what I did:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.93.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 esw0
10.93.1.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 esw0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
#
#
# vconfig add esw0 10
esw0.10: Features changed: 0x00005800 -> 0x00005000
# ifconfig esw0.10 10.93.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
# ifconfig -a
esw0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:02:03:04:14  
          inet addr:10.93.1.2  Bcast:10.93.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1509 errors:0 dropped:646 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:170634 (166.6 KiB)  TX bytes:2542 (2.4 KiB)

esw0.10   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:02:03:04:14
          inet addr:10.93.1.2  Bcast:10.93.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:308 (308.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

# ping 10.93.1.4
PING 10.93.1.4 (10.93.1.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=9.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.93.1.4: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.6 ms
^C
--- 10.93.1.4 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.5/1.2/9.4 ms
```

Nevertheless the esw0.10 vlan interface does seem to be transmitting the ping packets despite not adding the vlan tag.

```
# cat /proc/net/vlan/esw0.10
esw0.10  VID: 10         REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1
         total frames received            0
          total bytes received            0
      Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            0

      total frames transmitted            6
       total bytes transmitted          468
Device: esw0
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:0  2:0  3:0  4:0  5:0  6:0 7:0
 EGRESS priority mappings:
```

Here's a snapshot of the routing table after vlan configuration:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use  Iface
default         10.93.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 esw0
10.93.1.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 esw0
10.93.1.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 esw0.10
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
#
```

Comment: You have the same IP address on `esw0` and `ews0.10`. Linux has to pick one, and it prefers `esw0`, which does not have a VLAN tag associated with it, so your outgoing frames don't get tagged. The address should only be on `esw0.10`.

Comment: A generic tip, if you cant tag a vlan on your nic, as some cant, tag the switch port instead

Comment: @james-sneeringer - My ubuntu workstation works no matter if the address is there or not. I thought that too but it doesn't matter if the 'root' interface address is defined or not. My target platform still won't work either way.

Comment: @yagmoth555 - This is not an effort to get vlan's working from an admin point of view. I'm working towards getting vlan's working programmatically within our product.

Comment: @james-sneeringer - also, dumping the proc file esw0.10 indicates that its using the correct interface esw0.10